# C#: Cannot update control height while resizing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, resize

I have implemented a `UserControl` with a text `Label`. I want to adjust the control height when I resize the control width, to make the whole text visible all the time, like in the picture:
[image: sample]

I have customized the WinForms `Label` to calculate the `TextBounds` of the Label (the needed rectangle for the text) and I raise an event called `TextBoundsChanged` that indicates that the text rectangle size has changed (Note that this event is raised always while the label is being resized).

This works: I receive the event, then, I update my control height, but the height of the control really doesn't change!!

I suspect that the `TextBoundsChanged` event is raised when the `UserControl` is being resized. The `UserControl` is being resized also, so I'm afraid that **WinForms ignore the control height update while resizing**.

Am I right? Someone know how to workaround this issue?

Thanks in advance.

---

> **EDIT**: The user control not only show text. This is only a simplified sample. So, my user control needs to vertically grow when I reduce the width, in order to show the whole text in the label. the label is not a custom winforms label, because it renders HTML content. Also, I'm using .NET1, so the word wrap property is not available for me

Comment: What do you mean by "suspect". Can't you be 100% sure that the control is resized (at least "logically", not in the display) ?

Comment: This would happen if you set some height before resizing ends => the value you provided is simply overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) **or** [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of the Label within your UserControl and everything will work like a charme (you can also inspect the correct behaviour at design-time, by just resizing your UserControl). ;-)

Comment: +1 : This is a proved solution (That's what I usually do to get rid of manually resizing weird effects)

Comment: @Oliver: Read the comment at @Eric answer. This is only a simplified version. Dock and Anchor properties are well-known for me but in this case I need to manage the resize.

Comment: @Daniel: Where is your problem? You can simply open your `UserControl` with the VS Designer and place & configure components like you do in a form. Afterwards (hit built solution beforehand) put your UserControl on your Form and use it like any other control from the toolbox.

Comment: @Oliver: Yes. Thanks, I know how to use the Visual Studio WinForms designer. My user control needs to vertically grow when I reduce the width, in order to show the whole text in the label. the label is not a custom winforms label, because it renders HTML content. Also, I'm using .NET1, so the word wrap property is not available for me.

Comment: @Daniel: Please update your question with the points within your last comment. If we knew these constraints at the beginning, you wouldn't had so much *false positive* answers.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `UserControl`?  The behavior you want would be quite easy if you docked the label to the top of the form, turned autosize off and enabled word wrap.

Comment: Yes, it must be a user control. The sample is a simplified version. I show more information in the user control, and the text is the body of the control. Also the text label is and extended label that shows HTML parsed content.

Answer (score 0):

"WinForms ignore the control height update while resizing"
You mean UserControl ? I Highly doubt it

Make sure that your events go through all the right pipes/controls and perform invalidation when needed for the display (in the userContol or/and the embedding form). That normally shoudl do. If not, Use Docking as Oliver suggested.